# Using the gradle tomcat plugin

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle

I am trying to fiddle with the [gradle-tomcat-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) and I am having some issues with some of the preliminaries. Assuming that my WAR is present in one of my folders, what do I need to do in order to run the war in an embedded tomcat using gradles tomcat plugin? The readme mentions the `tomcatRunWar` but I am a little lost as to how to use it in my gradle file

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I want to "gradle war" followed by "... and deploy the war then start tomcat"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you have set up everything right

go to your root directory (your build.gradle file should lie there), then execute

```
gradle tasks
```

and you should see tomcats different tasks

- tomcatRun: Starts a Tomcat instance and deploys the exploded web
  application to it.
- tomcatRunWar: Starts a Tomcat instance and deploys
  the WAR to it.
- tomcatStop: Stops the Tomcat instance.
- tomcatJasper:
  Runs the JSP compiler (Jasper) and turns JSP pages into Java source
  using.

and then you just run it

```
gradle tomcatRunWar
```

myself I prefer jetty plugin